# Python Pool.map Showing each thread results

Tags: python, multithreading

i am trying to find a way to display each thread and what its doing while the program is running, i am using pool.map to spawn 3 threads at a time. I have it saved into a result variable, but when i print result, it just prints me a list of results, but only after the whole program finishes running. Has anyone been able to print out each thread while using pool.map?

Sample code

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool

def multi_test(args):
    return test(*args)

def test(a, b):
    return a*b

if __name__ == "__main__":
    pool = ThreadPool(3)
    results = pool.map(multi_test,[(33,22),(55,22),(77,88),(115,44321),(55,2245),(5532,7764),(5543,3322),(99865,55335),(2134,6743)]
    print results
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

Comment: Please list your code.  StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to illustrate the specific
problem you're having in a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example] https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For more information, please see [ask] and take the [tour].

Comment: I just revised the question and added some code to it.

Comment: I guess its not possible to print out each thread and what its doing?